# Override content of File in ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to gather facts for AWS VPC ID in file using the `lineinfile` module in ansible. But every time I gather those facts, it only creates new VPC ID in file but I need to override existing/previous VPC ID with new ID , so at a time I'm looking for only new VPC ID. How could I accomplish it ?

I used the below play but it doesn't working for me:

```yaml
  - name: VPN facts
    ec2_vpc_vpn_info:
       region: "{{ region }}"
       aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
    register: vpn_facts
  

  - name: add vpn facts into file
    lineinfile:
      path: vpn_facts.yaml
      state: present
      regex: "vpn_id"
      line: "vpn_id: {{ vpn_facts.vpn_connections[0].vpn_connection_id }}"
```

Comment: what's the error you face?

Comment: If you're sure that the line exists in the file, you can you the replace module. An example of the file would be helpful to get to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a version of Ansible that is 2.11 or newer, you can use the 'search_string' attribute instead of regex.
It will replace the last line that contains the search_string value with the value of the 'line' attribute.

```yaml
  - name: VPN facts
    ec2_vpc_vpn_info:
       region: "{{ region }}"
       aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
    register: vpn_facts
  

  - name: add vpn facts into file
    lineinfile:
      path: vpn_facts.yaml
      state: present
      search_string: "vpn_id"
      line: "vpn_id: {{ vpn_facts.vpn_connections[0].vpn_connection_id }}"
```